# Joomla extension/feature for adding articles to other sites

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

Is there a way for articles on joomla to be on another website without that user logging in to see it? The user should just see the article content and nothing else. This would be like a front end side version of articles for public users. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can publish your articles through RSS. In fact, just adding `?format=feed` to the end of the URL of any menu item of type "Category Blog" (or of type "Featured Articles") will generate the RSS page for that particular URL. All you need to do is to retrieve the RSS content on the other website (there are many tools to do that that are available in any CMS).

Comment: Thanks for that answer